# TSQL Group By issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

The following image shows a set of results with column titles:

> TotalEnquires Commission TotalBusinessWritten TotalPaidOut1 formname

I need to group by the `formname` and get the `SUM` of each grouped column for `totalenquires, commission, totalbusinesswrittenm, totalpaidout1`

Can anyone help please?

http://www.gumpshen.com/misc/tsql-help.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your issue?

```
SELECT formname, SUM(TotalEntries), SUM(TotalBusinessWritte), SUM(Commission), SUM(TotalPaidOut1)
FROM table
GROUP BY formname
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT formname, SUM(totalenquires), SUM(commission), SUM(totalbusinesswrittenm), SUM(totalpaidout)
FROM table
GROUP BY formname
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT formname,
      SUM(TotalEnquires),
      SUM(Commission),
      SUM(TotalBusinessWritten),
      SUM(TotalPaidOut1)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY formname
```